# share td width between tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two tables near each other.

I'd like to make the two tables have the same size for the first-column as if the rows were within same table. I don't want to set a fixed size for the column.

```css
table td:first-child {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Caption from first table</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Caption from second table</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The reason why I'm not using same table is because 2nd table is coming from a reusable component, so the two tables must stay separate.

One solution I see is to use JavaScript at run-time in different ways:

1. add all `<tr>` rows of 2nd table to 1st table and delete 2nd table. The problem with this approach is that CSS might stop working if we want each table to have separate styles and the CSS is using class names on `table` elements.
2. have a way to compute largest size of all first columns and apply to others. this is easy when all columns exist, but it would complicated if table / rows are dynamically added.

Comment: and it cant be a fixed size?

Comment: option 1 is the simplest solution. if we are talking about simple text data etc

Comment: @WalksAway nope, I mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, replacing the tables end/start tag.

*Update based on comment*

*To solve CSS rules, it would be very easy to give each table's first `tr` a table specific class and then use that for styling.*

*This tip work both on standalone and merged tables.*

```js
(function() {
  
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<\/table>(.*|[\r\n]*)<table>/gi,'');

})();
```

```css
table td:first-child {
  background-color: pink;
}

table .tbl1 td:first-child {
  color: blue;
}

table .tbl2 td:first-child {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="tbl1">
    <td>Caption from first table</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr class="tbl2">
    <td>Caption from second table</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, interesting approach. this would require however having the two tables in a container element like a `div`

Comment: @DonBox No it doesn't, you only need to adjust the regex to fit your markup structure, so what I show here is the concept of replace instead of for example move elements from on table to the other. This also has the advantage, once done, of having all rows (and their columns) behave as expected, compared to running a script measure a (or all) column(s) width on both load **and** resize.

Comment: the big disadvantage is that the CSS won't work anymore. if I have a CSS for 2nd table, once rows are merged into the first table, unless I want the first table to have same class name, things stop working.

Comment: @DonBox Well, my answer is based on your own question, _1. add all <tr> rows of 2nd table to 1st table and delete 2nd table_ ... so are you now saying that that statement is not viable anymore?

Comment: I guess so, my bad. I didn't think about CSS until now.

Comment: @DonBox The issue itself can be solved quite easily, using `tr:nth-child` as you know the amount of rows (or can easily count when doing the replace)

Comment: @DonBox Updated my answer with a suggestion to solve CSS rules. That tip work both on standalone and merged tables

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about a similar thing but the solution but you have to make sure you never put class names on the `<table>`'s. Basically, you have to always be aware that the two tables merge at runtime. I am starting to think this is not a good idea.

Comment: @DonBox If the data in the 2 tables belong with each other, merge, if not, don't.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar with heights on multiple divs in the past.

If you can edit the first td to have a CSS class, the following should work for you:

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="samewidth">Caption from first table</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="samewidth">Caption from second table</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var maxWidth = 0;
        $('td.samewidth').each(function () { maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $(this).width()); }).width(maxWidth);
});
```

(Note: requires jQuery and if you were to have a lot of tables, probably wouldn't be amazingly efficient!)

Comment: the issue is if you have a more complex app where there is additional JS code running on the elements to a apply a theme, depending on what that code is doing, sometimes there might be a race condition between that code and this code to compute the maximum width

Comment: You could always use this as a callback function of your applied theme, rather than using the jQuery onReady event. It would depend on where you render the tables as to whether this would affect the user's experience, i.e if they were below the fold the user wouldn't see any changes.